# Find the inequality

Tags: inequality

If $$ ax +\frac{b}{x} \ge c$$  $ \forall x \gt 0$  and $a , b , c $ are positive constant then , prove that $$ab \ge \frac{c^2}{4}$$
My work 
$$ax +\frac{b}{x} \ge c$$
$$ax +\frac{b}{x} -c \ge 0$$
$$ax^2 +b -cx \ge 0$$
$$D\le0$$
$$c^2 - 4ab \le 0$$
$$ab \ge \frac{c^2}{4}$$
Using $$AM\ge GM$$
$$(ax +\frac{b}{x})\frac{1}{2}  \ge \sqrt {ab}$$
$$ax +\frac{b}{x} \ge 2\sqrt{ab}$$
How I can conclude inequality between $\sqrt{ab}$ and $c$

Comment: Isn't the inequality that you desired to prove proved on the 6th line of your work?

Comment: Yes but how I will prove it by AM AND GM

Comment: Why $D\leq 0$ in the fourth line of your work?

Comment: Since quadratic is always greater than equal to zero

Comment: It is given that x is greater than zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$ax +\frac{b}{x} \ge c$,
choose $x$
so that
$ax = \frac{b}{x}$
or
$x^2 = \frac{b}{a}$
or
$x = \sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$.

Then
$c
\le a\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}+b\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}
=2\sqrt{ab}
$
or
$c^2 \le 4ab
$.